# how to retrieve users full data from mongodb using node js

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

i got one user resistor detail in my profile page but how to get all users registor details in my html profile page?

This is my one user register detail  get code from mongodb database

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {

```
  User.findOne(function(err,user){
    if (err)
            return done(err);

        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
        if (user) {
          console.log("THIS : " + user.country);
          res.render('profile.ejs', {
          user: user
        });
  }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to query all your `users`. So you need to user `User.find` which returns an array, instead of `User.findOne`.

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, Users){
    if (err)
        return done(err);

    if (Users) {
      console.log("Users count : " + user.length);
      res.render('profile.ejs', {
        usersArray: Users
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Then you need to set your `profile.ejs` to desplay all your objects, you need a loop for that.

```
<h3>My users IDs are: </h3>
<ul>
  <% if (typeof usersArray !== 'undefined' && usersArray.length > 0) {%>
    <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %>
      <li>ID: <%= usersArray[i]._id %></li>
    <%}%>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: /views/profile.ejs:29
    27|                 <ul>
    28|                   <% if (typeof userArray !== 'undefined' &&userArray.length > 0) {%>
 >> 29|                     <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %>
    30|                       <li>ID: <%= userArray[i]._id %></li>
    31|                       <li>ID: <%= userArray[i].username %></li>
    32|                       <li>ID: <%= userArray[i].country %></li>

usersArray is not defined i got this error in profile.ejs so how to solf this?@Fcmam5

Comment: You are using `usersArray` and `userArray` (without S), check your variable name in both server side (app.get) and your `profile.ejs`

Comment: How to design that details in the single box as a single user? @Fcmam5

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what do mean, can you explain more ? or do you have any examples ?

Comment: I got all data in my admin page now how to separate single users details one by one?  & how to add a style for that boxes?

Comment: `<ul>` and `<li>`tags in my answer are just examples you can simply replace these tags by any tag you want with any classes & IDs for example:
```
<h3>My users IDs are: </h3>
<div class="row">
  <% if (typeof usersArray !== 'undefined' && usersArray.length > 0) {%>
    <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="col-md-2>
        ID: <%= usersArray[i]._id %>
      </div>
    <%}%>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: place give the answer how to get all users details in a  table? Fcmam5

Comment: Simply hack my example, change`<li>` to '<td>` and `<tr>`

Comment: yeah, that's working now thank you so much...I need your help anymore,
Can I ask for my study Doubts??? @Fcmam

Answer (score 1):

use `find` instead of `findOne`

`findOne` will return the 1st result matching the query ( in your case there is no query so 1st result from the User model )

```
User.find({}, function(err,users){
   if (err & !users) {  ...  } // error
   // loop over users array
});
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findOne